# Accessing the prosper.com OAuth 2.0 API via R

Tags: python, r, rest, python-requests, httr

I am trying to access the `Prosper.com` API in the R programming language.

There isn't any online assistance for this task.

I have translated the following Python code into R:

```
import requests
url = "https://api.prosper.com/v1/security/oauth/token"
payload = "grant_type=password&client_id=<your_client_id>&client_secret=<your_client_secret>&username=<prosper_account_username>&password=<prosper_account_password>"
headers = { 'accept': "application/json", 'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Here is my translation from Python to R:

```
# Required Libraries
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# All API access information
Prosper_Base_Address <- "https://api.prosper.com/v1"
Request_URL <- "https://api.prosper.com/v1/security/oauth/token"
ClientID_Username <- "<prosper api key>"
ClientSecret_Password <- "<prosper api secret>"
Prosper_Account_Username <- "<username>"
Prosper_Account_Password <- "<password>"
headers <- fromJSON('{ "accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }')
payload <- "grant_type=password&client_id=ClientID_Username&client_secret=ClientSecret_Password&username=Prosper_Account_Username&password=Prosper_Account_Password"

# Create the endpoints
prosper_endpoints <- oauth_endpoint(NULL, "authorize", "accessToken",
                          base_url = "https://api.prosper.com/v1/security/oauth/token")

# Create the request app
prosper_app <- oauth_app("prosper_endpoints",
                   key = ClientID_Username,
                   secret = ClientSecret_Password)

# Get OAuth 2.0 credentials
prosper_token <- oauth2.0_token(prosper_endpoints, prosper_app,
                                config_init = headers,
                                user_params = payload)
```

This receives the error message:

> {
>       "error" : "Forbidden",
>       "error_description" : "Access Denied"
>     }

Thank you very much for your help!